# How do I install an OEM's launcher in my device?

Tags: launcher

I can easily install launchers available in the market like Nova launcher and others but not the launchers made by many OEMs (e.g. TouchWiz, Optimus UI, Xperia UI, Sense UI, Emotion UI by Huawei, MIUI by Xiaomi, Zen UI by Asus, Color OS by Oppo and the Cyanogen).

Anyone having a device made by those OEMs should be able to upload the APK of their launcher, so why it is not possible to install them? As an example, see [How to download and install Samsung TouchWiz launcher any Android device?](http://dottech.org/128776/how-to-download-install-samsungs-touchwiz-on-any-device-android/)

A good detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The apps made by OEM are specific to their devices and ROMs.

The apps may depend upon external libraries that the phones don't have..

> Anyone having a device made by those OEMs should be able to upload the APK of their launcher, so why it is not possible to install them? As an example, see [How to download and install Samsung TouchWiz launcher any Android device?](http://dottech.org/128776/how-to-download-install-samsungs-touchwiz-on-any-device-android/)

You can directly install the APK, but it won't work.
Because, you need to place the lib files in the /system partition necessary for that app.
That's what flashing the zip file does :)

The only way to get it working on other devices is [porting the app](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2476050) by editing and linking the necessary library files.